# Format time format in columns for Pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am building a pivot table with Pandas from json data. I'd like to format the column names before sending to to_string().

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

json_data = [
 {"year":2019,"month":"2019-11-01","sub_category":"Van fit out","category":"Vehicle","notes":"Heavy duty hooks","gross_amount":8.96}, 
 {"year":2019,"month":"2019-11-01","sub_category":"Fuel & oil","category":"Vehicle","notes":"Fuel","gross_amount":20.00},  
# more data  [...]
 {"year":2020,"month":"2020-02-01","sub_category":"Gutter Vac","category":"WC Equipment + H&S","notes":"Tape Measure + Bungi Cord + Plastic Membrane + Extension reel + Microfibre cloths + Waterproof Jacket","gross_amount":97.94}, 
 {"year":2020,"month":"2020-02-01","sub_category":"Trad equipment","category":"WC Materials","notes":"Spray Bottle + Microfibres","gross_amount":4.47}, 
 ]            

data = pd.DataFrame(json_data)

# Pivot the data:
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
            data, values=['gross_amount'], index=['category', 'sub_category'],
                    columns=['year', 'month'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0, dropna=True, margins=True)
# Add total rows for index level 0:
pivot = pd.concat([
        d.append(d.sum(skipna=True).rename((k, 'Total')))
        for k, d in pivot.groupby(level=0)
        ])

# Render to string:
string = pivot.to_string()

print(string)
```

The result is

```
                                  gross_amount
year                                      2019       2020     All
month                               2019-11-01 2020-02-01
category           sub_category
All                                      28.96     102.41  131.37
                   Total                 28.96     102.41  131.37
Vehicle            Fuel & oil            20.00       0.00   20.00
                   Van fit out            8.96       0.00    8.96
                   Total                 28.96       0.00   28.96
WC Equipment + H&S Gutter Vac             0.00      97.94   97.94
                   Total                  0.00      97.94   97.94
WC Materials       Trad equipment         0.00       4.47    4.47
                   Total                  0.00       4.47    4.47
```

How can I get the months to be formatted differently (in my case I need the month name)?
I have changed the month to a string in the dataframe before pivoting but then I lose the correct order.

Thanks

Comment: `data['month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['month']).dt.month_name()` ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but this loses the order for 'month' as the values are then sorted alphabetically

Comment: When pivoting Pandas automatically sorts the columns alphabetically, and dt.month_name() returns an index of strings, and strftime() also returns strings.

Comment: pivot always sorts, try replacing the month names as the last step

Answer (score 0):

that seems to work

```
# first get the column as date
data["monthdate"] = pd.to_datetime(data["month"])
# then format a column with the name
data['monthname'] = data["monthdate"].dt.strftime("%B")

# Pivot the data:
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
          data, 
          values=['gross_amount'], 
          index=['category', 'sub_category'],
          columns=['year', 'monthname'], 
          aggfunc=np.sum, 
          fill_value=0, 
          dropna=True, 
margins=True)

# Add total rows for index level 0:
pivot = pd.concat([
    d.append(d.sum(skipna=True).rename((k, 'Total')))
    for k, d in pivot.groupby(level=0)
    ])

# Render to string:
string = pivot.to_string()

print(string)
```

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten, same issue as anky's post, the months are then no longer ordered by date

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is possible with pivot_table(), but I managed it with group_by() instead, which accepts a `sort` [argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#groupby-sorting):

```
pivot = data.groupby(['category', 'sub_category', 'year', 'monthname'], sort=False)['gross_amount'].sum().unstack(['year', 'monthname'])
```

The `sort=False` stops it from sorting alphabetically, and preserves the original order the monts appeared, so the dataframe has to be sorted prior to grouping.